# How can I reset password of a user in ActiveAdmin which uses Devise for authentication?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

I would like to give admin/users option to reset **password** if they want? How can I do that in ActiveAdmin which uses Devise for authentication?
During reset password, it should ask for the **old password** and new password and password confirmation.

Then it should validate the old password and then change the password.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I did find something on Devise wiki for resetting the password, but will the same approach work with ActiveAdmin?